# mounting veracrypt partition on boot

Tags: command-line, mount, veracrypt

I want to mount automatically, at startup, a veracrypt partition. But the problem is that I can't mount it by the command line, 'cause, when I type this command:

```
# veracrypt -t --non-interactive -p some-password /dev/sdaX /media/veracrypt1/
```

I get the fallowing output:

```
Operation failed due to one or more of the following:
- Incorrect password.
- Incorrect Volume PIM number.
- Incorrect PRF (hash).
- Not a valid volume.

Enter password for /dev/sdaX:
```

and I have to put the password again, but this time, it mounts the partition.

So I need to mount it from the command line so I can set a script to mount it automatically at startup.

Comment: Have you tried `expect` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases usually the problem is caused by the special characters used within the password. So probably you need to quote the password:

```
... -p 'some-password' ...
```

or

```
... -p'some-password' ...
```

Comment: You are welcome, @Bob91!